# Is it normal for air to leak around blower

Tags: hvac, leak, air-leaks

I concered about gas leaking from furnace.  I sprayed soapy water around base where blower is and huge bubbles form.

We bought it brand new right after it was installed. It just wasn't heating the house so I called and had a tech come, and finally on the 3rd visit, he said when installed gas wasn't up high enough and caused a crack in the weld of burner plate. There's lots of soot and now leaks.

Does this look normal?
[image: photo]

Comment: The blower (motor+fan) and the combustion chamber should be two separate and isolated boxes or chambers in your furnace.  So the fact that you're getting some leakage from the blower section does not mean gas is leaking out.  If you're still worried, have a heating tech come in.

Comment: I assume this is a forced air heating system?

Comment: Air is not flammable gas. An air "leak" is not a problem unless it's huge. A flammable gas leak is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Air can leak out of the blower compartment if the seams have pulled apart or the "rubber weather stripping" has deteriorated allowing air to escape. Just air shouldn't be a problem. You can repair the seams with foil tape or mastik made for blower applications. However, you shouldn't be smelling any gas or fumes from burning gas. If you do, then it's time to get the pros involved for your own safety.